# Find links in HTML to see if match with an array

Tags: jquery

I have a small problem if anyone can help me solve. Basically, I have an array of keywords, and I'd like to see if any href links in the page matches with that. And if so, add some CSS effects to it. Here's what I have currently:

I made a simple "for" loop, so it will cycle through each array value, and change the CSS for it. But it doesn't seem to work for some reason.

```js
var arr = [
  'lovely',
  'HeartsandMinds',
  'pieces',
];

var i = 0;
for (; i < arr.length; i++) {
  $("a[href*=arr[i]]").each(function() {
    $(this).css("cssText", "opacity:0.3;");
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Examples of links inside a tags (note that links do repeat in the page):

<a href="http://www.example/profile/jenny">Link1</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/lovely">Link2</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/OrangesandApples">Link3</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/pieces">Link4</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/semantics">Link5</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/JOHNNY44">Link6</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/HertsandMinds">Link7</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/lolla">Link8</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/OrangesandApples">Link3</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/lovely">Link2</a>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please fix the error in the console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has various problems, i will use a single `each` to loop over the items in the array then add the opacity to each of the found items using `css("opacity", "0.3")`

```js
var arr = [
  'lovely',
  'HeartsandMinds',
  'pieces',
];

$.each(arr,function(i,v) {
 $("a[href*='"+v+"']").css("opacity", "0.3");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Examples of links inside a tags (note that links do repeat in the page):

<a href="http://www.example/profile/jenny">Link1</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/lovely">Link2</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/OrangesandApples">Link3</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/pieces">Link4</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/semantics">Link5</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/JOHNNY44">Link6</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/HertsandMinds">Link7</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/lolla">Link8</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/OrangesandApples">Link3</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/lovely">Link2</a>
```

Comment: Can't believe the answer was so simple. Thank you so much! This works pretty well!

Answer (score 3):

You can build a group selector and do it all at once:

```
$(arr.map(entry => 'a[href*="' + entry + '"]').join(",")).css("cssText", "opacity:0.3;");
```

Or with just ES5, since you didn't use any ES2015+ in your code:

```
$(arr.map(function(entry) { return 'a[href*="' + entry + '"]'; }).join(",")).css("cssText", "opacity:0.3;");
```

Live Example:

```js
var arr = [
  'lovely',
  'HeartsandMinds',
  'pieces',
];

$(arr.map(function(entry) { return 'a[href*="' + entry + '"]'; }).join(",")).css("cssText", "opacity:0.3;");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Examples of links inside a tags (note that links do repeat in the page):

<a href="http://www.example/profile/jenny">Link1</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/lovely">Link2</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/OrangesandApples">Link3</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/pieces">Link4</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/semantics">Link5</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/JOHNNY44">Link6</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/HertsandMinds">Link7</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/lolla">Link8</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/OrangesandApples">Link3</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/lovely">Link2</a>
```

---

Side note: For `.css("cssText", "opacity:0.3;");` you might want `.css("opacity", 0.3);` instead.

Live Example:

```js
var arr = [
  'lovely',
  'HeartsandMinds',
  'pieces',
];

$(arr.map(function(entry) { return 'a[href*="' + entry + '"]'; }).join(",")).css("opacity", 0.3);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Examples of links inside a tags (note that links do repeat in the page):

<a href="http://www.example/profile/jenny">Link1</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/lovely">Link2</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/OrangesandApples">Link3</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/pieces">Link4</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/semantics">Link5</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/JOHNNY44">Link6</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/HertsandMinds">Link7</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/lolla">Link8</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/OrangesandApples">Link3</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/lovely">Link2</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing:

1. Concatenation of `arr[i]` in the selector
2. Using ends with selector `$` as the array values seems to appear at the end of the `href` URL

```js
var arr = [
  'lovely',
  'HeartsandMinds',
  'pieces',
];

var i = 0;
for (; i < arr.length; i++) {
  $("a[href$="+arr[i] + "]").each(function() {
    $(this).css("cssText", "opacity:0.3;");
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/jenny">Link1</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/lovely">Link2</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/OrangesandApples">Link3</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/pieces">Link4</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/semantics">Link5</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/JOHNNY44">Link6</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/HertsandMinds">Link7</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/lolla">Link8</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/OrangesandApples">Link3</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/lovely">Link2</a>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your solution works perfectly over my existing code!

Comment: @Bob glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this match your requirement

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a href="http://www.example/profile/jenny">Link1</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/lovely">Link2</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/OrangesandApples">Link3</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/pieces">Link4</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/semantics">Link5</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/JOHNNY44">Link6</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/HertsandMinds">Link7</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/lolla">Link8</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/OrangesandApples">Link3</a>
<a href="http://www.example/profile/lovely">Link2</a>



<script type="text/javascript">

var arr = [
  'lovely',
  'HeartsandMinds',
  'pieces',
];

$(document).ready(function(){


  $("a").each(function(i,html) {
           for (i=0; i <arr.length; i++) {
       var getMatchtext = $(html).attr('href').split('/profile/')[1];

    if(getMatchtext==arr[i]){
        $(this).css("cssText", "opacity:0.3;"); 
     }   

            }

  });

})
```